# What is the best way to create an updatable MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

What should I do to make my MVC application to be updtable? Saying 'updatable' I mean once open a time the app connects to the server, detects that newer version is on and it should self update.

On the desktop app it is quite simple: i just download it and then by using the batch file, I update the main exe file using replace.

So what should I do with `MVC3` app, hosted in `IIS7`?

Comment: MVC application can't be not uptatable. All the data in on the server, click F5, and **UPDATED!**

Comment: MVC is a DLL located in the IIS's inetpubb folder or whatever. I need that to be updated NOT by republishing it (because there will be lots of the applications like that). I need the app to self update there.

Comment: Why not just redeploy your application or script your deployment via ftp, visual studio, publish, etc? Web apps are best pushed, rather than pulled like desktop apps, although not always and you may have a better reason here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with another service on your server machine. This service will check for updates. If update is available then it downloads whole updated application from the remote store (ftp) and replaces the old version with the updated version. Another option is [MSDeploy/WebDeploy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1073/introduction-to-web-deploy/) which allow you to remotely update/synch your web application.